# creating a 4 icon hierarchy in a dropdown

Tags: icon, interface-design

I am designing a spacial automation player that can run trough:

1. a single instruction
2. a single step (a group of instructions)
3. a section (a group of steps)
4. script (running all elements)

I am trying to create icons that will explain the relationship between them as well as the meaning of each icon. I tryed to avoid using literal meaning icons, like a footstep icon for steps, because I think that it's missing the point.

Thanks

[image: This is the wireframe]

[image: And this is the initial design I made]

Comment: This question would be better placed at User Experience https://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, its not a UX issue, it's a design issue, I am trying to build a visual connection between a set of icons @wesrside

Comment: I'm immediately confused about the difference between steps 2 and 3. I fully understand the paradigm: One instruction, a predetermined group of instructions, all instructions... but where the fourth choice comes into play I am confused.

Comment: To expand on that, I don't think your mixing the nouns "instruction", "step" and "element" is helping. Are they all the same thing?

Comment: @mayersdesign Thanks for the notes, it is indeed confusing, so let me try to clarify it: instruction is the most basic unit. every step contains a batch of instructions. a section is a group of instructions, and script describe a mode that runs all of the sections.  

for example, lets take pees:
each pea is an instruction, each pod of peas is a step, each plant is an instruction and the entire field is the script.

Comment: UX is design, but the scope i broader and in anycase doing the hierarchy for a GUI is much better suited for UX as you will get a broader and better motivated answer of on UX. But the question is fine here too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either set of icons explains your situation yet. What I understand the icons need to convey, in order:

1. Single
2. Several
3. Many
4. All

Some of your icons are already known symbols, like the folder. I would avoid these that already have meaning.

I think your first code symbol is successful, brackets with a slash inside.

Maybe for Several you can make brackets slash dot dot slash and for many . For All you can use the good old infinity symbol.

One, several, many, all, I can help think of more possibilities to convey this.